# Pandas split multiple columns of lists

Tags: python, pandas

A similar question has been answered here
[Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

However, the solution can only apply to a single column of list, how about if I have multiple columns of lists, is there any better ways to splitting those columns instead of using the solution above to break down the column one by one?

For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"teams": [["SF", "NYG"] for _ in range(7)], "cities": [["NY", "LA"] for _ in range(7)]})

    teams       cities
0   [SF, NYG]   [NY, LA]
1   [SF, NYG]   [NY, LA]
2   [SF, NYG]   [NY, LA]
3   [SF, NYG]   [NY, LA]
4   [SF, NYG]   [NY, LA]
5   [SF, NYG]   [NY, LA]
6   [SF, NYG]   [NY, LA]
```

to

```
  team1 team2 city1 city2
0    SF   NYG    NY   LA
1    SF   NYG    NY   LA
2    SF   NYG    NY   LA
3    SF   NYG    NY   LA
4    SF   NYG    NY   LA
5    SF   NYG    NY   LA
6    SF   NYG    NY   LA
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution while writing this question,

```
splits = [pd.DataFrame(df[col].tolist()).add_prefix(col) for col in df.columns]
clean_df = pd.concat(splits, axis=1)
```